# Bug with NotifyCollectionChangedArgs?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm rolling my own observable collection class. My class inherits `ICollection<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

My `ICollection<T>.Remove(T item)` method is as follows:

```
public bool Remove(T item)
{            
   if (_innerCollection.Contains(item))
   {
      List<T> removes = new List<T>();
      removes.Add(item);
      _innerCollection.Remove(item);
      CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove,removes));
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }

}
```

This throws an `InvalidOperationException` with "Collection Remove event must specify item position."

According to the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653206(v=vs.110).aspx) I have chosen a valid constructor.

> `public NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action,
>       IList changedItems)`
>
> *action:*
>
> Type: System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction
>
> The action that caused the event. This can be set to Reset, Add, or **Remove**.

I get that somewhere internally it wants an index. Investigating the constructor [in the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/notifycollectionchangedeventargs.cs,b2f64d10459f52ac) shows that the internal/private constructor substitutes -1 for the index using this public constructor. That should be enough to satisfy my use case. But the heck if I know why it is failing. Any ideas?

Edit: the stack trace ends here:

> MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)

And in the reference docs [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/EnumerableCollectionView.cs,2cda116dcb4ad2fa) I obviously see where the exception is thrown. But it's not fair I can publicly use that constructor to drive off a cliff.

Comment: The exception seems reasonable to me. Why don't you just use [the constructor that accepts an index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653208(v=vs.110).aspx), and pass the correct index? Do you have a legitimate problem here? It's not clear that you do.

Comment: My use case requires a `SortedSet` backing collection, i.e. index isn't available. I might try and corral `SortedList` into doing the work.

Comment: Your second link has moved to https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/EnumerableCollectionView.cs, at least for dot net framework.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the use of `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(instanceOfYourCustomCollection)` or just a simple `{Binding InstanceOfMyCustomCollection}` somewhere in your code. When creating a `CollectionView` over your collection or in fact just binding to it (which will create a `CollectionView` internally) then you need to pass the removed item's index, because the `CollectionView` expects it and will fail otherwise, as you noticed.

I agree that the documentation doesn't make this crystal clear.

Comment: This isn't just a documentation issue.  As far as I can tell, the collection change notification system and WPF stuff that depends on it is meant to work with *collections*, which includes sets that do not provide index access (at least, not as Microsoft implemented them). Microsoft has a really bad habit of using the term collection and then only supporting lists.  They said collection, then they need to support collections generally, not just lists.  That should be part of the cost of occupying "collection" names.